# When are Compound Indexes still relevant in MongoDB 2.6, given the new Index Intersection feature?

Tags: mongodb

Mongo 2.6 introduced [Index Intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/). It appears to me that whatever can be achieved using Compound Index, can be more easily achieved using Index Intersection, and with greater flexibility (as it could support more types of queries). 
However, Mongo's documentation says that:

> Index intersection does not eliminate the need for creating compound indexes. ([Link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-compound-indexes))

Then it goes on explaining the disadvantages of using compound index relatively to index intersection. I could not understand what is the **advantage** of using such index instead of letting mongo intersect several indexes to fulfill the query.

---

**Edit**: I recommended reading the [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071?focusedCommentId=508454&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-508454) @Sammaye provided in his answer for detailed explanation of index intersection vs. compound index by Mongo's dev David Storch. Bottom line:

> index intersection should not be considered a replacement for compound indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points to answer could be:

- Index intersectioning is limited to two indicies at a time: (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071)

> Index intersection is on by default. The query planner currently limits itself to 2 indices at a time, though this limit may increase in the future.

- Index intersectioning is not a replacement for compound indexes, but merely, like `$where` to be used when you have no real choice. Index intersectioning is not the fastest, nor most scalable way to find documents within a collection so you must be careful about just how much intersections you use.
- It is also good to note there are limitations on exactly what indexes MongoDB can intersect: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort